# Mean time of arrival at state $0$ for a specific markov chain on $\mathbb{N}_0$

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

> Let $\{X_n\}$ be a Markov chain on $\mathbb{N}_0$ such that 
>   $p(x,x+1)=p(x,0)=1/2$ for all $x\in \mathbb{N}_0$. Find $E(T_0~|~X_0=1),$
>   where $T_0=\inf\{k\geq 0:~ X_k=0\}.$

**Attempt.** If $g(x)=E(T_0~|~X_0=x),~x\in \mathbb{N}_0$ then, according to one-step analysis:

$g(x)=\frac{1}{2}g(x+1)+\frac{1}{2}g(0)+1,~x\in \mathbb{N}$ and $g(0)=0$, that is $g(x+1)=2g(x)-2,~x\in \mathbb{N}$, with general solution $g(x)=c2^x+2,~x\in \mathbb{N}$. Since $g(0)=0$, we get $c=-2$, so $g(x)=2-2^{x+1},~x\in \mathbb{N}_0$, while $g(x)\geq 0$, a contradiction. Where seems to be the problem in the above solution?

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: You write $x \in \mathbb{N}$ for the equation $g(x + 1) = 2g(x) - 2$, but then invoke the condition $g(0) = 0$, which has nothing to do with the equation, since $x \in \mathbb{N}$. I think you need to use a different condition here. Any idea which one?

Comment: My concern was exactly this, that is how to set $x=0$ to get $c$, since the equation (and the solution) holds for $x\in \mathbb{N}=\{1,2,\ldots\}$. Any hint for the necessary condition needed?

Comment: Notice that the initial state $x$ does not change $T_0$, as long as $x \ge 1$. So, we conclude that $g(x) = g(y)$ for all $x,y \ge 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, that probability of reaching state $0$ from state $1$ in exactly $k$ steps is $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k$ (the only way is $1\to2\to3\to...\to k \to 0 $), so
$$E(T_0|X_0=1)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{2^n}=2$$
A few days ago there was question about calculating similar sum:
[link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2131479/prove-that-sum-limits-n-1-infty-fracn3n-frac34)

Comment: But $p(1,0)=1/2$, i.e. in one step we can move from $1$ to $0.$

Comment: @NikolaosSkout yes, but we don't want to calculate the minimum steps needed to reach 0.

Comment: I see! You use the definition of the mean value for a discrete random variable. Great!